# Mongodb : Clone all documents in a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongoDB Collection and I want to clone all the documents in the same collection but all the new documents should have a unique "_id" field.

```
Document within my Collection 'event'
{
"_id" : ObjectId("fsfd324324324wer"),
"active" : false,
"channels" : [ 
    "1", 
    "2"
],
"created" : ISODate("2013-06-16T00:25:57.781Z"),
"curationId" : ObjectId("51bd0612b0bf4e7035bfea00"),
"deleted" : true,
"lower_name" : "garden",
"name" : "Garden",
"user" : "abc"
```

}

The query which I tried is as below :

```
    db.event.find().forEach(function (x) {
    delete x._id;
    db.event.insert(x);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming collection name as myCollection.

```
db.myCollection.find().forEach(function (x) {
    delete x._id;
    db.myCollection.insert(x);
});
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it doesn't really copy the documents

Comment: is it not inserting document? , it is pretty simple and working for me

Comment: For me, it doesn't insert any documents.

Comment: post your query what you have used with sample document also

Comment: do you want to clone all document in same collection or to different collection ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48736/discussion-between-sumeet-and-pi-horse)